# Docker compose error while creating a portus demo environment why?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a portus envirnment using docker compose, but I get this error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
ERROR: for crono Container command 'bin/crono' not found or does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 63, in main
AttributeError: 'ProjectError' object has no attribute 'msg'
docker-compose returned -1
```

Comment: It appears that the container 'crono' has no command 'bin/crono' avalaible inside

Comment: And how to add it ? To crono file ?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably that the Data Space Available value is near of 0 MB. You can check this value using the command "docker info".

If this is your case you can resolve your problem following the next steps:

- If you haven't your images uploaded to a docker repository you should save it using the next command -> "docker save -o DockerImageName.tar "
- su
- systemctl stop docker
- mkdir /new/path/to/docker
- vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
- Add the next lines to your daemon.json -> { "graph": "/new/path/to/docker" }
- systemctl start docker

And you could try up you container again

- su docker
- If you have saved your docker images in the first step you should load the images with the next command -> "docker load -i DockerImageName.tar"
- cd /path/to/docker-compose
- docker-compose up -d